# How to selectively setState for an object with two array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

How would I add new objects to the data: [] using setState() for the following code or replace data entirely??

```
    const [tableState, setTableState] = useState<TableState>({
    columns: [
      { title: "First Name", field: "firstName" },
      { title: "Last Name", field: "lastName" },
    ],
    data: [
      {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
      },
      {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
      },
    ],
  });
```

`setState(prevState => ({...prevState.tableState, ???}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a new user, Joe Bloggs. It would look like this (note that the setter is `setTableState` — the setter you got from `useState` — not `setState`):

```
setTableState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, 
    data: [
        ...prevState.data, {
            firstName: "Joe",
            lastName: "Bloggs"
        }
    ]
}));
```

What that does:

1. Creates a new object which is a shallow copy of `prevState`, but
2. With a new `data` property, that
3. Has the original data, plus the new object

---

But stepping back a bit: That state item is probably too complicated. With hooks and `useState`, you usually want to keep your state really finely-grained. In this case, I think there are at least two separate state items:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState<ColumnType[]>([
    { title: "First Name", field: "firstName" },
    { title: "Last Name", field: "lastName" },
]);
const [data, setData] = useState<DataType[]>([
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
    },
    {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
    },
]);
```

And you'd set new `data` state like this:

```
setData(data => [
    ...data,
    {
        firstName: "Joe",
        lastName: "Bloggs"
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing between `hooks` and conventional `setState`.

From the above code, you should be updating your state using `setTableState` function instead.

```js
setTableState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  data: [
    ...prevState.data,
    {
      firstName: 'New FirstName',
      lastName: 'New Last Name'
    }
  ]
}))
```